# 这个 and 个 Pinyin

Tags: mandarin, tones

According to Google Translate the Pinyin for 这个 is 'Zhège' but the Pinyin for 个 is 'Gè'.  I've looked at several links referring to tone changes (e.g. [here](http://www.learnnc.org/lp/editions/mandarin1/4481)) but nothing I can find explains the different tone given to 个.

Could anyone clarify what is happening here?  Thanks.

Comment: When someone say 'mountain', he may dismiss the 't', similar circumstance.

Comment: search site using "neutral tone", note esp. comments #1,3 of  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21092/does-%e8%8a%8b%e9%a0%ad-have-a-different-pronunciation-in-taiwan-mandarin-vs-mainland/21104#21104

Comment: It is not uncommon for characters to lose their tone in certain phrases. Surely you have come across the word 妈妈 which is pronounced māma, the two 妈 characters have different tones

Comment: 个 in 这个 is pronounced slightly, no tunes applied. even if without 个 meanings of the statement is still complete.

Answer (score 1):

this is common in Chinese. it is called "neutral tone". some characters(个，么，着，了，etc) , when they are used at the end of a word or sentence, will change to "neutral tone": ge, me, zhe, le, etc. they will be pronounced in a brief/short way (sounds like the short version of the first tone) . Besides 这个, there are more: 看*着*，知道*了*，什*么*，找不到*了*

Answer (score 0):

Finding where "words" begin and end in Chinese is more challenging than in languages that are written with spaces, in which case we generally adopt the convention that a "word" is what is separated by spaces (major exception: Vietnamese).

While most *words* 词 in Chinese will be two or more characters, people often talk about individual *characters* 字. Oftentimes, *pinyin* readings are presented as a series of character readings, rather than as guides to pronounce whole words.

In order to learn to pronounce Chinese as it is spoken, it is important to pay attention to *words* as they are spoken. Building up the pronunciation of a word by individual character pronunciations may work sometimes, but it is easier to get a more accurate pronunciation for some word by consulting a 词典 *word* dictionary (as opposed to a 字典 *character* dictionary) or, of course, by hearing the language in actual use.